# $.get request in loop with different URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to check a text file, if it contains that text, then  move onto the next get request and check another text file to see if that second text file contains certain text.

I've tried putting it into a while loop like this:

```
    function testMessage()
    {
        const filePaths =
        [
            "http://example.com/trigger.txt",
            "http://example.com/userexceptions.txt",
            "http://example.com/message.txt"
        ];

        const trigger = "true";
        var currentStage = 0;
        const finalStage = 2;
        var breakLoop = false;

        while (currentStage < finalStage)
        {
            $.get(filePaths[currentStage], function(data)
            {
                if (currentStage == 0)
                {
                    const compareText = data.localeCompare(trigger, "en", {sensitivity: "base"});
                    if (compareText == 0) //if the first text file contains the trigger "true", continue
                    {
                        someGlobalVariable = true;
                        currentStage++;
                    } else {
                        breakLoop = true;
                    }
                } else if  (currentStage == 1) //if the second text file contains the username of the current user, break the loop
                {
                    const rawUsers = data;
                    const userExceptions = rawUsers.split(';');

                    if (userExceptions.indexOf(currentUser) > -1)
                    {
                        console.log("User exception is: " + userExceptions[userExceptions.indexOf(currentUser)]);
                        breakLoop = true;
                    } else {
                        currentStage++;
                    }
                } else if (currentStage == 2)
                {
                    globalNotification = data;
                    notification.global(globalNotification);
                    console.log("Global notification displayed.");              
                } else {
                    console.log("We're here now.");
                }
            }, 'text')
            .fail(function()
            {
                console.log("Global notifications failed at stage: " + currentStage);
            });

            if (breakLoop)
                break;
        }
    }
```

I also tried using a switch statement instead of multiple if-else statements, and led to the page breaking as well, so I assumed it wasn't breaking out of both the switch and loop properly.

When I run this, it seems that the loop never ends so it breaks the page?

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but why wouldn't currentStage ever be 2? If the current user isn't in the userexceptions.txt file, wouldn't it increment currentStage from 1 to 2?

Comment: It'll hit 2.. then exit the loop because `currentStage` is not less than `finalStage`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. Although, even when I set the `const finalStage` to 3, instead of 2, the page is still breaking for `Reason: Render process gone`, which based on some quick Googling seems to be due to a never-ending loop?

Comment: The fact that Ajax requests are asynchronous is probably the issue here. The while loop completed long before any of the requests return results. If you need to wait for the result of a request before starting the next one then use Promise chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement this in a very different way. I think you should read about `fetch` and `promises` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). That will solve this kind of problem easily!

Anyway... I try to mak a minimal chang on your code to work. There is how:

- Remove your control variables, as you can use the array length and test results.
- Using the array length, you can simply add more items to the array and it'll just work.
- As each file need a different test, I change the array of string URLs to an array of objects, where we can add a `test` method to each one.
- The `breakLoop` var was replaced by the `test` method return.
- The `breakLoop` test was replaced by the recursion test.
- The while loop was replaced by the async recursive `getFiles` method. That makes `testMessage` async too, so i did ad a `callback` argument to it.
- The `getFiles` is called after its declaration on index 0.
  ** It uses jQuery's ajax and on result it runs the current stage test.
  ** When return true and this is not the last item, it calls `getFiles` for the next stage.
  ** So... that means it is not parallel. It is sequential as (i believe) you need.

```js
    function testMessage(callback)
    {
        const trigger = "true";
        const files =
        [
            {
                url: "http://example.com/trigger.txt",
                test(data) {
                    const compareText = data.localeCompare(trigger, "en", {sensitivity: "base"});
                    if (compareText == 0) //if the first text file contains the trigger "true", continue
                    {
                        someGlobalVariable = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else return false;
                }
            },
            {
                url: "http://example.com/userexceptions.txt",
                test(data) {
                    const rawUsers = data;
                    const userExceptions = rawUsers.split(';');

                    if (userExceptions.indexOf(currentUser) > -1)
                    {
                        console.log("User exception is: " + userExceptions[userExceptions.indexOf(currentUser)]);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            },
            {
                url: "http://example.com/message.txt",
                test(data) {
                    globalNotification = data;
                    notification.global(globalNotification);
                    console.log("Global notification displayed.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        ];

        (function getFiles(currentStage)
        {
            $.get(files[currentStage].url, function(data)
            {
                if (files[currentStage].test(data))
                {
                    if (files.length > currentStage+1) getFiles(currentStage+1)
                    else callback(null, "Success!")
                }
                else callback(Error(`Stage${currentStage}'s test fail.`, null))
            }, 'text')
            .fail(function()
            {
                console.log("Global notifications failed at stage: " + currentStage);
            });
        })(0);
    }
    testMessage(console.log)
```